# Total sum For Looping in Ionic angular js show NAN

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

so I am attempting to calculate total sum of for looping when I am inserting value in the input box, however my total sum is NaN, not sure where Did I do wrong, can someone help me?

here is my coding in ts file:

```
days: number[] = []

 

     ngOnInit(): void {
        for(let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
          this.days.push(i);
        } 
      }
    
    
      ionViewDidEnter() {  
        this.crud.getAllInfo();
      }
    
      calAmount(){
        let sum=0;
        for(let d of this.days){
        sum= sum+this.amount
        }
          return sum;
      }
    
    and here is my html file
    
        <div *ngFor="let day of days; let i = index">
           <ion-item>
          <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
            <img src="assets/icon/document.png">
          </ion-thumbnail>
            <ion-label position="floating" >Day #{{day}}</ion-label>
            <br>
            <input [placeholder]="day" [(ngModel)]="day.amount">
          </ion-item>
        
        </div>
        
        <p>Total Amount:{{calAmount()}}</p>
```

Comment: `  sum= sum+this.amount` where is `this.amount` ? i think `d.amount`

Comment: i changed to d.amount declared amount as number amount:number; and my day as 'days: number[] = []' and got stated 'Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'number' as error, do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a small mistake in your `calAmount` function.

```
calAmount() {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let d of this.days) {
    sum = sum + d.amount || 0; // <-- Note `d.amount` instead of `this.amount`
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Here's a faster approach:

```
calAmount() {
  return this.days.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.amount || 0, 0);
}
```

Also note the `|| 0` part. Given the numbers come from an input, it might be possible that when removing the content of the inputs you receive an `undefined/null` value, so it's better to add a fallback to `0` in order to fix possible runtime errors.

Comment: Can be improved by changing `d.amount || 0` so that null and undefined are not evaluated!

Comment: The definition of `days` is `number[]`, so no `undefined | null` values in place.

Comment: typescript is just for end user, if user clears the input in html,  it will give you null or undefined, so it will evaluate to NaN, just suggesting improvement not criticizing

Comment: Valid point, did not think about this. Thanks @NarenMurali.

Comment: i changed to d.amount declared amount as number amount:number; and my day as 'days: number[] = []' and got stated 'Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'number' as error, do you know why?